# Delete all not referenced (by foreign key) records from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a address table which is referenced from 6 other tables (sometimes multiple tables). Some of those tables have around half a million records (and the address table around 750000 records). I want to have a periodical query running which deletes all records that are not referenced from any of the tables.

The following sub-queries is not a option, because the query never finishes - the scope is too big.

```
delete from address where address_id not in (select ...)
and not in (select ...) and not in (select ...) ...
```

What I was hoping was that I could use the foreign key constraint and I could simply delete all records for which the foreign key constraint does not stop me (because there is no reference to the table). I could not find a way to do this (or is there?). Anybody another good idea to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this ways

```
DELETE
    address
FROM
    address
    LEFT JOIN other_table ON (address.id = other_table.ref_field)
    LEFT JOIN other_table ON (address.id = other_table2.ref_field)
WHERE
    other_table.id IS NULL AND other_table2.id IS NULL
```

OR

```
DELETE 
FROM address A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM other_table B
  WHERE B.a_key = A.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM OTHER table)
```

Comment: Make your code a bit more readable: DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT foreignKey FROM other_table)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this by first creating a TEMPORARY TABLE (t) that is a UNION of the IDs in the 6 referencing tables, then run:

```
DELETE x FROM x LEFT JOIN t USING (ID) WHERE x.ID IS NULL;
```

Where x is the address table.

See 'Multiple-table syntax' here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Obviously, your temporary table should have its PRIMARY KEY on ID. It may take some time to query and join, but I can't see a way round it. It should be optimized, unlike the multiple sub-query version.